# 18.04 - cannot extract vmtools - not enough free space to extract tar

Tags: software-installation, vmware, 18.04

I have run `apt autoremove`.

During initial installation of 18.04 as a virtual machine in VMware Workstation 14 Player, VMtools was not installed.  I selected *Player → Manage → Reinstall VMtools*.  Using *Files* I opened *VMWare Tools*.  I right-clicked on `VMwareTools-10.2.0-7259539.tar.gz`.  When I selected option *Extract To…*, no matter what I did I received the error message above about not enough free space.

Comment: what does `df -h` say?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) once it is reopened and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! :-) I took the liberty to revert the change that added the answer but you can always review a post’s history through the link below it.

Comment: I also have this issue. I've increased (with GPart) the `sda1` partition size to about 100GB, but I still have this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Move the contents of the mounted drive to the desktop. I had the same issue, copied it over to the desktop and chose "Extract here" worked after that.

Comment: I would like to note that you first need to click on the `VMWare Tools (DVD)`, then you drag and drop the `.tar` folder (inside `VMWare Tools (DVD)`) to the desktop.